# ListView I can't reference in R.id.list?

Tags: android, listview

```
  ListView  ls=(ListView)findViewById(**R.id.list**);
    ls.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
     AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(ListAllTracks.this);
     adb.setTitle("LVSelectedItemExample");
    // adb.setMessage("Selected Item is = "+String.valueOf(ls.getItemIdAtPosition(position)));
     adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
     adb.show();

      }
          });

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the layout.xml where is located your listview, i think you just have to extend your class as ListActivity.

Comment: A ListActivity is not required for the ListView to work.

Answer (score 5):

It's fine to use the android id's.  Just change your code to use

> findViewById(android.R.id.list)

and you'll be done with it

Answer (score 1):

change

```
<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
```

to

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
```

extend your Activity as ListActivity

```
public class myActivity extends ListActivity {
```

then override the onListItemClick function.

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {
     super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);               
     AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(ListAllTracks.this);
     adb.setTitle("LVSelectedItemExample");
    // adb.setMessage("Selected Item is = "+String.valueOf(ls.getItemIdAtPosition(position)));
     adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
     adb.show();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" >
```

do it

please look here for more details iin the answer

[What is difference between @+id/android:list and @+id/list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355614/what-is-difference-between-id-androidlist-and-id-list)

Answer (score -1):

It should be this:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"> 

</ListView>
```

Often, if a view id doesn't appear in the resource class (e.g. `R.id.????`), that's a sign that there's a problem with the XML layout.

I'm currently using the following code, and it works for me.  I am **not** using a ListActivity.  Instead, I placed a ListView control in a standard Activity.  I am using a custom adapter, but you can use a standard `ArrayAdapter` if you need to.

```
List<Unit> unitList = ... get my list of stuff ...
ListView unitListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.unitListView);
UnitListItemAdapter adapter = new UnitListItemAdapter(this, unitList);  
unitListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: hmm I  try it with that sample first  but  I  had an  error "Your content must have a Listview whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'"

Comment: Is there an error somewhere else in your XML layout file?  If so, then none of the IDs from that file will appear in your resource (R) object.  The above code works for me.

Comment: Hi  bpoter ,  no  I  do not  use  anywhere  list  as  a name for a ListView :
Again this is now my XML   code :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ListView android:id="@+id/list"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ListView>
</LinearLayout>

now  I can reference  but it break when I call  Activity where I fill ListView :"Your content must have a Listview whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Comment: If you can reference it, then there is no longer a problem in your XML layout, but instead there is a problem in your java code.

Comment: hmm but i  java code  there is no any error until calling this activity which contain a ListView I can Paste here code of my class it is bigger then allowed :)

Now if I put  "@android:id/list"  I  do not  have  error and  I see ListView values but now  when I wont to creat onItemsClick I can reference  R.id.list

Comment: I  resolved this  error after few  hours :(  android & eclipse is  so confuse  (when you start work with after Microsoft & VS)

I get some data from db to my list and use:
 lv.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));

this need extends ListActivity :

I change to only extend Activity and : lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));

USE setAdapter !!!!

Resolved when I replace setListAdapter with setAdapter :))))

Thanks all of you who try to help me specialy bpoter :)