# Difference between @android:id/list and @id/list

Tags: android

what is the difference between

```
@android:id/hello
```

and

```
@id/hello
```

I ask this, cause apparently we MUST use @android:id/list in the Class when we want to extend ListActivity.

Comment: please check below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355614/what-is-difference-between-id-androidlist-and-id-list

Comment: You don't HAVE to use "@android:id/list". It's recommended and convention, but not 100% necessary. I was "forced" (more like curious) to implement a ListView without the default Android ID when a partner of mine messed with the code in such a significant way that to rollback the changes would have been worse than going along with it. `<ListView android:id="@+id/msgList"/>`

Answer (score 2):

`@android:id/hello` is the default ID as set by Android (except that I don't think they have a hello set).

`@id/hello` would be an ID set specific to your application.

Answer (score 1):

The `@android:*` identifiers refer to pre-defined identifiers in the SDK. Those are the only identifiers known to the framework (like ListActivity). Identifiers like `@id/list` refer to your app's resources.