# Strange exception in ListView Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-resources

I am getting an exception but could not get where exactly the exception occured.
I searched but could not get the my project name in the stacktrace.

Below is my stacktrace

```
02-13 15:48:23.741: W/dalvikvm(416): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
02-13 15:48:24.026: W/System.err(416):    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File  from xml type layout resource ID   #0x102000a
02-13 15:48:24.036: W/System.err(416):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1916)
02-13 15:48:24.036: W/System.err(416):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1871)
02-13 15:48:24.036: W/System.err(416):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:731)
02-13 15:48:24.036: W/System.err(416):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:318)
02-13 15:48:24.036: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:332)
02-13 15:48:24.036: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
02-13 15:48:24.036: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
02-13 15:48:24.046: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
02-13 15:48:24.046: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
02-13 15:48:24.046: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
02-13 15:48:24.046: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
02-13 15:48:24.046: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
02-13 15:48:24.046: W/System.err(416):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-13 15:48:24.046: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
02-13 15:48:24.046: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
02-13 15:48:24.046: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
02-13 15:48:24.046: W/System.err(416):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-13 15:48:24.046: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:909)
02-13 15:48:24.056: W/System.err(416):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-13 15:48:24.056: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
02-13 15:48:24.056: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1238)
02-13 15:48:24.056: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1044)
02-13 15:48:24.056: W/System.err(416):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-13 15:48:24.056: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-13 15:48:24.056: W/System.err(416):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-13 15:48:24.056: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
02-13 15:48:24.066: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
02-13 15:48:24.066: W/System.err(416):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
02-13 15:48:24.066: W/System.err(416):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-13 15:48:24.076: W/System.err(416):  at    android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
02-13 15:48:24.076: W/System.err(416):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
02-13 15:48:24.076: W/System.err(416):  at    android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
02-13 15:48:24.076: W/System.err(416):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
02-13 15:48:24.076: W/System.err(416):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-13 15:48:24.076: W/System.err(416):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-13 15:48:24.076: W/System.err(416):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-13 15:48:24.076: W/System.err(416):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-13 15:48:24.086: W/System.err(416):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-13 15:48:24.086: W/System.err(416):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-13 15:48:24.086: W/System.err(416):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-13 15:48:24.086: W/System.err(416):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 02-13 15:48:24.086: W/System.err(416): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
 02-13 15:48:24.086: W/System.err(416):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlAssetNative(Native Method)
02-13 15:48:24.086: W/System.err(416):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:485)
02-13 15:48:24.086: W/System.err(416):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:1898)
02-13 15:48:24.086: W/System.err(416):  ... 40 more
```

My project package name is

```
com.stylingandroid.IntelligentLayout.SecondaryLayout;
```

I could not see my package name at all
Before I had an exception which I set it right the exception was

```
02-13 15:39:25.756: W/System.err(379): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

I changed my ListView Id to `android:id="@id/android:list"` and in java code I changed the adapter as

```
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.id.list, STATE));
   getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

My class extends ListActivity

```
public class StateList extends ListActivity{
```

Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Comment: change ListActivity to Activity

Comment: then how will I work with setListAdapter `setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.id.list, STATE));
       getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);`
when changed to just Activity I am getting as method setListAdapter is undefined.
    `super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);`
method on listItem is undefined for Activity.
The method `getListAdapter()` is undefined for the type StateList.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242136/how-can-i-implement-a-listview-without-listactivity-use-only-activity

Comment: thanks, but I have many TextView in my layout and my layout is big, I tried with calling the layout first and then the TextView later, but getting exceptions. I get exception here ` setContentView(R.layout.statelist_layout);` and later I use TextView ` setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.id.listitem, STATE));` The exception I am getting is `W/dalvikvm(455): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)`.

Comment: Did you try to clean and re-build project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a resource is missing 0x102000a. You need to reverse reference this value from your R.java and find the resource that is causing this issue.

I also suspect that you have used a id of your own, and not android.R.id.list to identify your resource in your layout xml file.

Refer to [What is difference between @+id/android:list and @+id/list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355614/what-is-difference-between-id-androidlist-and-id-list)

ListView is not as straight forward as other widgets. Takes a bit of more detailed study to get it working. I went through that cycle :).

Answer (score 1):

Please check the ListView specs in Android developer forum:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

The below method needs a layout resource which is used to display each item in the listview.

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, COUNTRIES));
```

list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

So, here every list item will be shown as a TextView.

Comment: thanks, but I have many TextView in my layout and my layout is big, I tried with calling the layout first and then the TextView later, but getting exceptions.
I get exception here ` setContentView(R.layout.statelist_layout);` and later I use TextView ` setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.id.listitem, STATE));`
The exception I am getting is `W/dalvikvm(455): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My class was extending `ListActivity`, I change to `Activity` and now is running.