# Error when trying to launch new Activity android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I'm trying to launch an android activity from my Main activity, but I get force stop.
The `logcat`error is like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

But the activity that I try to launch already has a `ListView` with the id "list".
Any advice is appreciated.
**UPDATE:** Still can't figure out what's wrong.
Here's my code:

`activity_all_apps.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context="com.example.app.AllAppsActivity">

 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and
`AllAppsActivity.java`

```
public class AllAppsActivity extends ListActivity
```

Comment: Please show layout xml which contain ListView

Comment: [Take a look at the accepted answer on this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040374/runtimeexception-your-content-must-have-a-listview-whose-id-attribute-is-andro)

Comment: paste some code here, what have you tried?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355614/what-is-difference-between-id-androidlist-and-id-list) is another link to consider. Posting code would probably help, but chances are the two links will offer enough help to get you past this. Let us know how it worked out or post some code if the links don't help.

Comment: Change id to `@android:id/list`

Answer (score 0):

In your XML layout file related to this Activity you should have a `ListView` element that whose id is `@android:id/list`. Something like this.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</ListView>
```