# Android Studios - Cook book project is not compiling. Can't figure out why. Detailed Pictures provided

Tags: java, listview, android-studio

I have been following this video and trying to figure out why my code is not compiling even though their code is compiling.

[Recipes Simple Android Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLjTSKEJpqIeASjLTzMbsG0vEyTDOGwaqc&v=MLS0TtX1kM4)

At the time of 3:40 he makes his xml layout. I did the same but it does not let me put the type of id he put on there which is important for the later code.
This is where I am having the problem.
[image]

30 minutes into the video I run into another problem. I used the exact code but it also did not compile.

[image]

at 31:41 you can see all of the code is compiling. On mine it is not. I am trying to figure out why that is.

[image]

This is the specific video of what I am trying to accomplish. I am trying to make a cookbook where I can have a ListView of recipe options and when I click on the option it goes into a different activity and displays the recipe instructions.

I am new to Android Studios so some things that might be obvious I have not learned yet. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Is there a reason why we don't see src/main folders on the right panels on your screen ? We can see them in the path on the top. I ask because I see them on my own android studio on a personal project.

Comment: i just cropped the picture.

Comment: Why is it `"@+list/thumb"` ? I have never used that before. I always use `"@+id/thumb"`

Comment: That is what I was thinking. But in the video he puts list/thumb.

Comment: Have you extended the same classes the author of the video did? You may or may not find this link helpful (One of the comments: "The + implies adding something to R, whereas omitting the plus simply implies referencing something that is already defined. – David Hedlund"): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355614/what-is-difference-between-id-androidlist-and-id-list